# Dynamically adding new routes from the server to the app-routing.module (Angular 11)

Tags: angular, routes

Hello everyone I am creating an application on Angular+Node.js. There is a need to create new menu items by the user. Each menu item will be a separate page with a separate address that should eventually be dynamically added to the routes array in the `app-routing.module`. Naturally, I also dynamically want to set a certain component for certain routes. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to do this, because all routes are set during the initial initialization of the application. And then, for some reason, new elements are added to this array, but the routes do not work.

The only method of adding that I learned about is that you can perform the following action in the `AppRoutingModule` constructor.

```js
export class AppRoutingModule {
  private routes = [];
    
  constructor(private router: Router, private service: ContactsService) {
    this.router.config.unshift(
      { path: 'test', component: SettingsPageComponent },
    );

[...]
```

That is, through the config property, add some additional route. But even in the same constructor, if I try to load routes dynamically from the server, nothing comes out.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  service.getContacts().subscribe(contacts => {
    this.recursionRoutes(contacts.menu);

    this.router.config.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.canActivate) {
        this.routes.forEach((route) => {
          this.router.config.push({ path: route, component: SettingsPageComponent })
        })
      }
      this.router.resetConfig(this.router.config)
    })
    console.log(this.router.config)

  })
}, 1000)

console.log(this.router.config)
```

Although new elements are essentially added to the `this.router.config` array. But the routes don't work this way.

[image]

When trying to go to the address, it throws an error.

[image]

```js
this.router.resetConfig([
  { path: 'somePath', component: SomeComponent},
  ...
]);
```

I found this method here, but for some reason it does not work. What is defined in the `AppRoutingModule` during initial initialization, then it works. Other routes that are additionally added do not work.

Comment: why not useing lazy loading with configurable routes as needed when module load ?!

Comment: the problem is that it is necessary to add new routes not just as the module is loaded, but you need to add dynamically routes as you create, for example, menu items. I've never done this before and I don't know how to use lazyloading. If there are any examples, I will be happy to see examples

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
this.router.resetConfig([
 { 
    path: 'somePath', component: SomeComponent
 },
 ...this.router.config
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a medium article showing how I've done something similar that what you're trying to do: https://medium.com/@benjperney/create-angular-routes-dynamically-from-server-data-15a385582f48
I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).